# ESP32 with onboard ethernet interface

Tags: ethernet, esp32, poe

I'd like to know which is the best and chapest way to add an ethernet port (*possibly POE enabled*) to an ESP32 board.

Alternatively I'm looking for a cheap ESP32 with onboard LAN.
Any idea?

Comment: please define `best`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's normally off-topic, but:

- ESP32 boards with Ethernet and PoE include:

  - [Olimex ESP32-POE-ISO](https://www.olimex.com/Products/IoT/ESP32/ESP32-POE-ISO/open-source-hardware)
  - [Lilygo TTGO T-Internet-POE](http://www.lilygo.cn/claprod_view.aspx?TypeId=21&Id=1344&FId=t28:21:28)
  - [wESP32](https://www.crowdsupply.com/silicognition/wesp32)
- ESP32 boards with Ethernet but no PoE include:

  - [Neonious One](https://www.neonious-iot.com/neoniousOne)
- ESP32-based device with Ethernet and PoE:

  - [APR Brother AB BLE Gateway V4](https://store.aprbrother.com/product/ab-ble-gateway-4-0) (also includes an nRF5282)
- M5 Stack have several PoE devices at https://shop.m5stack.com/pages/search-results-page?q=poe They include PoE adapters, PoE devices...

The Olimex board schematics are available [here](https://github.com/OLIMEX/ESP32-POE-ISO/tree/master/HARDWARE) (they're open source).

The APR Brother AB BLE Gateway V4 schematics are available [here](https://github.com/AprilBrother/ab-hardware/tree/master/ab-ble-gateway-v4) (for inspiration, but I don't think they're open source).

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. Very interesting. Which is a best place on wich post questions like this?